# Trying to get User location on a map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

My code is totally fine, i want to get user location on the map as soon as the app is opened. But the app just crashes. Also the program is set to update location and add a marker as soon as its changed, nut that's also is  not working. Here's the code

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager)    getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        Location location= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        double lat =location.getLatitude();
        double lng =location.getLongitude();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title("Marker"));

        // Add a marker and move the camera

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Double lat = location.getLatitude();
        Double lng = location.getLongitude();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title("Marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 10));
        Log.i("Latitude", lat.toString());

    }
```

Comment: can you post crash logs ?

Answer (score 0):

try This.
getLastKnownLocation returns if location is there in cache otherwise it returns null
add a check there

```
 if(location!=null)
 {
 double lat =location.getLatitude();
double lng =location.getLongitude();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).title("Marker"));
}
```

2 solution use google play services fusedlocation api for better management with location refer here http://coderzpassion.com/android-location-using-google-play-services/

3 try this to addMarker

```
public void drawMarker(double lat,double lon)
{
    if (mMap != null) {
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title(" Maps Tutorial").snippet("Android Ruler");
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
 // Moving Camera to a Location with animation
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(12).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        mMap.addMarker(marker);
    }
}
```

for more details refer here http://coderzpassion.com/android-google-maps-v2-tutorial-with-markers/

Comment: i used this also but the app just crashes, i m running it on a Oneplus one with marshamallow 6.0.1

Comment: the thing is, in any case no marker appears on a map (if it runs) or it just crashes as soon as it is launched. Why isnt there a marker anywhere on map, my location services are on every setting is totally fine.

Comment: @KunalYadav check if location provider is enabled or not. if enabled then only code to get location

Comment: thanks the code works now. Next i am looking to create a app that tracks user location and can show the path he moved using a polyline on a map. Do you have a tutorial for that?

Comment: @KunalYadav i posted the link in my answer. anyways refer here:- http://coderzpassion.com/android-google-maps-v2-tutorial-with-markers/